# Send email from an App directly - Swift

Tags: swift, email, button, action, textfield

I want to send a mail from my application. I am doing my first steps with Swift and i have stuck at a point. I want to press a button and send email directly. I want take data for Subject and MessageBody from my TextField. Including the sender's data from my TextField (please check screenshot)
How do it?
This my code :

```
@IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["primer@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't your first steps include running a search?  And where is the screenshot?  And WHAT IS YOUR QUESTION?

Comment: @ElTomato search what?I added a question

Comment: Similar topics...  You aren't the first to ask this question.  Not even the 10th...

Comment: @ElTomato and?thanks for the info))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you want to send the email behind the scenes, without the user seeing an email view controller come up?  If that's what you want, you can't do it from your (front end) code. Apple doesn't want apps to be able to send emails in an automated fashion without the user hitting the send button him or herself.  If you wanted to, you could program the functionality to send an email from the server side of your app.

Comment: I want the user to remain in the app even after pressing the button SEND

Comment: When the email view controller comes up, the user is still in your app, even though the email view controller looks exactly like the email application that comes with your iPhone.

Comment: can I take data for Subject and MessageBody from my TextField for email?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of `mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")`, do this:  `mailComposerVC.setSubject(subjectTextField.text)`, if subjectTextField is the name of your text field where the user types the subject.  Then do the same type of thing for the message body.